# Connect 3/8-16 bolts at 90 degrees

Tags: bolts, hardware, fitting

I'm finding that I am needing to connect two standard 3/8-16 (coarse) bolts at a 90 degree angle for mounting, like an elbow fitting would do. I need to be able to thread them in individually, because it's a tight space. But I cannot find any sort of nut or hardware that can thread in to it. I thought "3/8" street elbows would work, but they are too large. Suggestions?

[image]
Here is a diagram. I obviously don't have any CAD experience but I hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: Do think you will have to make up something.  Street elbows are for plumbing and thread size/type does not match.  I would use a long type of nut(as shown in answer), and cut it in half at 45 angle.  Weld the two half's together to make a 90 degree angle.

Comment: There's a lot of [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here... Maybe tell us what you're trying to accomplish (include a pic or a drawing). There are a lot of creative thinkers who might come up with an answer you haven't thought of yet that would avoid this conundrum.

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/13061/connecting-3-8-16-bolts-at-90-degrees) to multiple stacks. If you've found what you think is a better place for it, request to have the question migrated, instead.

Comment: Hi! You have a couple of unregistered accounts. Please consider [registering](/help/why-register) one of them, then [merge them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts) and [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and most importantly [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers). Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: what are you trying to drill? ... if you describe the apparatus in detail, then this may be a better fit ... https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Do the centerlines have to be in-line?

Comment: Can you weld ??

Comment: would a block of <favourite material> with two holes drilled in it do?

Comment: Are you trying to mount the drill so that it slides along the track?  If so, there should be several easier ways to do this.

Comment: can't use bent bolts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach that might work is to use an angle bracket at each corner, held to the threaded rod with two 3/8" nuts on each end.

Comment: I think this is the most viable solution for what I have. I don't have access to a welder, though it would be a good solution. And this doesn't require a super-straight hole (due to the nut securing it, not the metal

Answer (score 12):

Find someone with a drill press and a 3/8-16 tap.  Take a cube of steel, drill holes in adjacent faces, and tap them for the thread size.

Comment: Or make a thick sheet metal right angle (or hacksaw off a short length of square tube etc), drill and tap.

Answer (score 11):

Pipe thread and screw thread are different even if you could find the right size elbow.  What you might have to do is take a threaded coupler or two and have them welded together.

I've never seen a threaded 90 like that, but it might exist for some specialized purpose.

[image: all-thread coupler]

Answer (score 6):

Do think you will have to make up something.

Street elbows are for plumbing and thread size/type does not match.

I would use a long type of nut(as shown in @JPH1618's answer), and cut it in half at 45 angle.  Weld the two half's together to make a 90 degree angle.

Could also weld plain nuts to an angle bracket.

Answer (score 6):

There is such a thing as a [*hinged threaded standoff*](https://www.mcmaster.com/spacers/hinged-female-threaded-round-standoffs/), that is basically a non-rigid version of what you're looking for.  (No endorsement implied, in fact the linked company doesn't even carry them in the size you need.)  They are available with every combination of male & female threaded ends.

[image: catalog image]

Comment: That was my first thought too.  It answers the question that was asked, although I doubt it solves OP's *actual* (unstated) problem.  It will be tough to get two of those tight enough while ensuring their center lines remain aligned.

Answer (score 1):

Get some 3/8-16 studding, aka threaded bar, and bend it. Your diagram suggests you don't need a sharp bend. A bench vice and hammer would suffice to make the bend in something as light as 3/8 threaded.

Answer (score 0):

A block of aluminium for each side. The vertical hole may need tapping, but the horizontal one could be drilled straight through, as the bolt going that way would need to thread into the drill (judging by the diagram).

It may even be possible to drill straight through both, depending how the vertical thread needs to be fixed.